# Having problem to change the style with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I started this project a few days ago and I'm trying to make a to-do list but got a problem with the addEventListener:

So I added a list and things are going well, but when I want to mark the items as completed by the button that has generated with the innerHTML, It does not change the style and says:

Cannot set properties of null (setting 'addEventListener')

Although, I tried the onclick method, but didn't help.
So what should I do about it?

```
let myList = [];

const inputFieldEl = document.getElementById("input-el");
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn");
let changeBtn = document.getElementById("done-btn")
let toDoList = document.getElementById("todoList");

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let inputValue = inputFieldEl.value;

    myList.push(inputValue);

    clearInputField();

    toDoList.innerHTML += `
    <li id="item">
        <button id="done-btn"></button>
        ${inputValue}
    </li>`;
});

changeBtn.onclick = () => {
    document.querySelector("#item").style.backgroundColor = "#F1C40F";
}


function clearInputField(){
    inputFieldEl.value = ""
};
```

That's my code and you see, after clicking the changeBtn, It should change the background color of the `<li>` tag that has created.[Prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvHON.png): It's the prototype, I just added so maybe it could be helpful

Comment: `id's` have to be unique. You create an element multiple times all with the same id. Beyond that, you should append an element correctly by using `createElement` and not by using `innerHTML` which is comparably slow and poses security issues. Last but not least, do not use `style` in 2023 anymore but rather use `classList` to either add, remove or toggle a CSS class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicate ids, you're generating multiple list items with the same id="item". IDs should be unique within a page. Instead of using IDs for identifying individual list items, you can use classes or other attributes.

And you're adding event listeners to dynamically created elements, you need to consider event delegation since the elements might not exist when you initially set up the listeners.

Here's the modified version of your code

```
let myList = [];

const inputFieldEl = document.getElementById("input-el");
const addBtn = document.getElementById("add-btn");
const toDoList = document.getElementById("todoList");

addBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let inputValue = inputFieldEl.value;

    myList.push(inputValue);

    clearInputField();

    const newItem = document.createElement("li");
    newItem.innerHTML = `
        <button class="done-btn"></button>
        ${inputValue}
    `;
    toDoList.appendChild(newItem);
});

toDoList.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains("done-btn")) {
        const listItem = event.target.parentElement;
        listItem.style.backgroundColor = "#F1C40F";
    }
});

function clearInputField(){
    inputFieldEl.value = "";
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim, I was struggling with this situation for days and you solve it for me, I appreciate your help buddy. 

Way to go!

Comment: Although, I found another problem. So I manage to change the style of `li` tag , but the styles just appear on the first item and as I go through the second and so on, it does not change the style of `button` tag for the second time and so forth

Comment: Change the querySelectorAll(".done-btn") as you are trying to access this class. For ID it will be ("#exampleID"). 

And you're not accessing the individual button correctly. You should use the parameter of the forEach() callback function to access each button.

doneBtns.forEach((doneBtn) => { // Each doneBtn will be called from the doneBtns here
      doneBtn.style.backgroundColor = "#8E44AD";
      doneBtn.style.border = "3px solid #F1C40F";
    });

Answer (score 1):

```js
toDoList.addEventListener("dblclick", function(event) {
  if (event.target.classList.contains("done-btn")) {
    const listItem = event.target.parentElement;
    const doneBtn = document.querySelectorAll("done-btn");
    listItem.style.backgroundColor = "#F1C40F";
    listItem.style.color = "#8E44AD";
    doneBtn.forEach(() => {
      doneBtn.style.backgroundColor = "#8E44AD";
      doneBtn.style.border = "3px solid #F1C40F";
    })
  }
});
```

Here is the sample code. So the problem is the function won't change the style of the button for the second time and other times

Comment: This feels more like an addition/need to edit the question rather than an answer here especially since `querySelectorAll("done-btn")` does not seem to be correct - but no HTML so the context for that might change this fact.